# how to check array indexes contain null value

Tags: android, listview, arraylist

i have one array object that contain total 300 indexes. each index has different values and some index are null, my problem is when i print this array in custom listview, i get some index with null value, so how do i check each index contain value or not. this is my result of listview,

[image]

is there any trick in listview that remove blank line,  or how to manage array.
this is what i tried..

```
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayProducts.size(); i++) {
         if (!arrayProducts.get(i).getProductSeries().equals(" ") && arrayProducts.get(i).getProductSeries() != null) {
         modal = new ProductModal();   
            modal.setProductSeries(arrayProducts.get(i).getProductSeries());
       }
        arrayProducts2.add(modal);
     }

  Log.d("modelCheck", String.valueOf(arrayProducts2.size()));
  arrayAdapter1 = new ProductSerachAdapter(mcontext, arrayProducts2, type);
                    listSearch.setAdapter(arrayAdapter1);
```

i have total 47 index with value and other are blank, and my list view has total 300 index bcz of arrayProduct().size(); i want only 47 index with listview, how do i make it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> remove the space inside " ".

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrayProducts.size(); i++) {
                if (!arrayProducts.get(i).getProductSeries().equals("") && arrayProducts.get(i).getProductSeries() != null) {
                    modal = new ProductModal();
                    modal.setProductSeries(arrayProducts.get(i).getProductSeries());
                }
                arrayProducts2.add(modal);

            }
            Log.d("modelCheck", String.valueOf(arrayProducts2.size()));
            arrayAdapter1 = new ProductSerachAdapter(mcontext, arrayProducts2, type);
            listSearch.setAdapter(arrayAdapter1);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrayProducts.size(); i++) {
     if (!arrayProducts.get(i).getProductSeries().equals("") && arrayProducts.get(i).getProductSeries() != null) {
     modal = new ProductModal();
     modal.setProductSeries(arrayProducts.get(i).getProductSeries());         
     arrayProducts2.add(modal);
   }
 }
```

You were performing `arrayProducts2.add(modal);` outside if statement.

Comment: You're welcome. Also, try playing with `ArrayDeque`, it doesn't allow **null** elements ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should first check that if index value is null or not

Like This

```
if (arrayProducts.get(i) != null && !arrayProducts.get(i).getProductSeries().equals(" ") && arrayProducts.get(i).getProductSeries() != null)
```